# Zoom out content of a div not the DIV itself.

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, zooming

Does any one know if it is possible to zoom out the contents of a div much like browser zooms out a page?

I am creating an application that loads and page into a div. However, I would like to be able to load the content without scroll bars. This would mean that the content inside of the the div not the actual div would have to be zoomed out. I know that this could be done with an image but can it be done with HTML content. If so do you have any examples using jquery or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Mmm...what have you tried so far? Can you post any code? IMO the purpose of stackoverflow is not to ask "How can I do this?" but rather, "I tried to do this, but how can I make it work?"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do what you're trying to do would be to use `<iframe>` with `scroll` set to `none`.

Parsing someone else's data (if you don't have the rights to it) into your own formatting has been deemed copyright infringement.