# Zoom inside of a div, changing the inner elements but not the div itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I am looking for a way to zoom into a div element. Since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170840/zoom-out-content-of-a-div-not-the-div-itself) did not provide some code example, I decided to post the following.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXnSz/5/) already helped, but as you can see in [my adapted jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXQf3/903/), the whole div scales. I just want the image inside to scale. the div should have an overflow if zoomed in (also scroll bars).
Is this possible without including other scripts e.g. panzoom?

**HTML**

```
<div id="pane">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#pane').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
  var stage = $(this);
  scaleData = getZoom(stage);
  if ( e.originalEvent.detail < 0 ){
    setZoom( scaleData.curScale * '.9', stage );
  }
  else{
    setZoom( scaleData.curScale * '1.1', stage );
  }
});



function setZoom(scale, el){
  scale = Math.round(scale*10)/10;
  el.attr({
    style:
    'zoom: '+scale+';'+
    '-webkit-transform: scale('+scale+');'+
    '-moz-transform: scale('+scale+');'+
    '-o-transform: scale('+scale+');'+
    '-ms-transform: scale('+scale+');'+
    'transform: scale('+scale+');'
  });
}

function getZoom(el){
  var curZoom = el.css('zoom');
  var curScale = el.css('transform') ||
      el.css('-webkit-transform') ||
      el.css('-moz-transform') ||
      el.css('-o-transform') ||
      el.css('-ms-transform');
  if ( curScale === 'none' ){
    curScale = 1;
  }else{
    //Parse retarded matrix string into array of values
    var scaleArray = $.parseJSON(curScale.replace(/^\w+\(/,"[").replace(/\)$/,"]"));

    //We only need one of the two scaling components as we are always scaling evenly across both axes
    curScale = scaleArray[0];
  }
  return { curZoom: curZoom, curScale: curScale };
}
```

**CSS**

```
div#pane{
    height: 20em;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly the solution is to change the 2nd line of the JS you provided in a JSFiddle to:

```
var stage = $(this).find('img');
```

I just included `.find('img')` to the end of what you had there. Previously you were zooming the entire div, now it zooms just the img tag.

Comment: Alternatively, `$('#pane img')` on line 1.

Comment: Okay! This already works, I did not think about this when posting my question. I tried to break a bigger issue down to this. my div#pane is actually parent of `jsplumb` elements (also divs). Should I edit my question?

Comment: I don't think I understand where you're coming from. Do you mean to zoom in the div without the scroll bars appearing?

Comment: no I want the scrollbars to appear, the div itself should stay the same size, all inner divs should be zoomed

Comment: So I recon this is what I did. If you want not only the img but all the other elements to be zoomed in, then you can either change `find` to `children` function, or add another div and change the id inside `find`.